# Change button text keyboard in IONIC 2

Tags: angular, ionic2

[keyboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IJG8b.png) Is it possible in ionic 2/3 to change the text of a button of the keyboard? 
I want to change the text of the “**return**”-button  to **OK** or **Search**.

Comment: can you post your code and then explain what you are trying to do?

Comment: No need Code, I want just change buuton keyboard text; return in IOS become OK or Done

Comment: `<input type="search">` is pretty much the closest, easiest, solution. Input elements can have several types that affect touch display keyboards. Check out a list here: https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_form_input_types.asp

Comment: Yes, it's for search but how to show Done button or other text ?

Comment: it is achieved by the way you use forms